# Editing your network profile's Top Questions and Top Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-questions, top-answers

**Make editing of the Top Questions and Top Answers possible.**

Currently, based on some code, Stack Exchange chooses your top questions and answers from different sites and formats them into a list by votes to show on the network profile. But sometimes, the best questions/answers (or the ones you're most proud of) may not be the highest voted, and due to that, will not show as your top network posts. I do not know if this is possible, but I would like to have a feature that would let me edit the Top Questions and Answers so that I could display the answers that I think are my best, not based on votes.

The way I think of it, there would still be the minimum score of 5 for a question or answer to qualify for a Top Question or Top Answer, and there could (possibly) be a limit on how many questions and answers are displayed. I don't know whether or not this is possible or if it would work at all, but I am curious to see everyone else's take on this idea.

Comment: So, what you're really asking for is to change it from "Top Questions" and "Top Answers" to something like "Questions the User Wants to Highlight" and "Answers the User Wants to Highlight". You appear to be *really* asking for giving the user control of the list (perhaps with some limits).

Comment: One very simple workaround would be to just list all your posts that you want to highlight in your "About Me" section.